# New NSAttributedString multiline

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uilabel, nsattributedstring, multiline

I worked UILabel. But setLineBreakMode is deprecated.
I have been using NSAttributedString.
but UILabel setLineBreakMode is 
After that UILabel setNumberOfLines else does not work.

Before:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(42.0f, 10.0f, 275.0f, 50.0f)];
label.text = @"XXXXXX";
memoLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
memoLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
memoLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;
memoLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:11];
memoLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

IOS 6 after:

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
NSAttributedString *string
    = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text
                                  attributes:[NSDictionary
                                              dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:11],
                                              NSFontAttributeName,
                                              paragraphStyle, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName,nil]];
[paragraphStyle release];
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(42.0f, 10.0f, 275.0f, 50.0f)];
label.attributedText = string;
[string relase];
```

I want to be the same before and after the display.
How to display multiple lines?

Comment: Many be you find here.
Have you seen <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8921858/nslinebreakbytruncatingtail-scrolls-text-when-set-as-a-paragraph-style-in-nstext>?

Answer (score 4):

The `lineBreakMode` property isn't deprecated in iOS 6.  It has simply changed the names of the constants.  The old constants are deprecated, but still available.  You can use the new constants even if you are deploying to an older iOS, because the constants are just enum values.  The old names and the new names have the same values.  So, just set `memoLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail`.

Your example code doesn't appear to take advantage of any attributed string specific features.  If you don't need an attributed string, just keep using a plain string.  That still works in iOS 6.

Answer (score 2):

Use `NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail` instead of `UILineBreakModeTailTruncation`